# "A call to an OS function failed" when loading Windows-1252 XML file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, msxml6, eoserror

**Edit:**

The error was indeed in the handling; `parseError` also fails ans reveals the real error; see [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346060/msxml6-error-loading-valid-windows-1252-document-system-error-2146697210) for that error.

**Old question:**

Somehow, sometimes the code below generates an exception when loading XML using the msxml unit in Delphi XE.
It fails on Windows XP Professional x86 SP3 using MSXML6 and Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1 using MSXML6.

```
procedure TXMLEOSErrorTestCase.Test;
var
  XmlDocument: IXMLDOMDocument3;
  XmlFileName: string;
begin
  XmlDocument := CoFreeThreadedDOMDocument60.Create();
  XmlFileName :=  TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDirectoryName(ParamStr(0)), '1-Normal.xml');
  if not XmlDocument.load(XmlFileName) then
    RaiseLastOSError();
end;
```

This error occurs during the XmlDocument.load method:

```
EOSError at  $00423B2D
A call to an OS function failed
```

I trimmed the XML down to the XML found below.

This is the hex dump of the XML file:

```
000000: 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65  72 73 69 6F 6E 20 3D 20 <?xml version =
000010: 22 31 2E 30 22 20 65 6E  63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D 22 "1.0" encoding="
000020: 57 69 6E 64 6F 77 73 2D  31 32 35 32 22 3F 3E 3C Windows-1252"?><
000030: 52 4F 57 20 43 69 74 79  3D 22 E0 22 2F 3E 0D 0A ROW City="."/>..
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><ROW City="à"/>
```

Why does the error occur?

(The XML loads perfectly fine in .NET and other environments not using MSXML6).

--jeroen

Comment: Does the error really occur *during* the `load` method, or does the exception you've quoted actually occur because *you* called `RaiseLastOSError`? I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in *SysUtils.pas*, that error message is the one that's given when [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx) returns zero. The [documentation for `IXmlDomDocument.load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722.aspx) does not advise you to call `GetLastError` to discover the reason for the failure. The last-error value for your thread is probably the default zero value.

Instead, inspect the document object's `parseError` value. It will give you an [`IXmlDomParseError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757019.aspx) object that tells you where and why the problem occurred.

Comment: Oh brilliant; I mixed up the two error paradigms without even noticing. Isn't that an odd form of blindness :-) Will follow up with a new question and the right error (from parseError).