# MSXML alternative

Tags: xml, delphi, open-source, msxml, xmlhttprequest

Is there a MSXML alternative?
I think MSXML clashes with previous versions.
Also I prefer open source, at least tools with source.
Delphi is my choice but I can manage c/c++.
It should support all of construction, navigation and xmlhttp interface without MSXML dependency.
Thanks for any lead

Comment: What makes you think MSXML clashes with previous versions?

Comment: I think it's not MSXML that's causing a problem but a missing DLL on the target system that is used to test it.

Comment: Note that MSXML behaviour depends heavily on which version of MSXML you have installed, especially when you want to do XPath things.

Comment: @Jeroen, I knew there were XPath differences between 3 and 4, but didn't know there were big changes afterwards.

Comment: @Bruce: For instance this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346060/msxml6-error-loading-valid-windows-1252-document-system-error-2146697210

Answer (score 4):

Also you can have a look at [NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html), it is Open Source.

Comment: Hosted at Google Code now: http://simdesign.googlecode.com

Answer (score 3):

Using TXmlDocument you can use either MSXML or the open source implementation, Open XML (http://www.philo.de/xml/), that comes with Delphi. If using TXmlDocument the version of MSXML used is the latest version available on the machine, so it won't clash.

Comment: MSXML does not use the latest version, it is up to the user which version is used. MSXML does not have a version independant program identifier. If you would look at the TXMLDocument you will see that it first tries to use MSXML 6.0, and fallback to an earlier version if the latest is not available.

Comment: @The_Fox, that is what I meant to say, so I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @The_Fox: actually that depends on what version of Delphi you're using. For example Delphi 2007 doesn't know about MSXML6 out of the box.

Comment: @Idsandon: I know, it's the same with Delphi 7. That is the drawback of not using version independent identifiers. You can only support what is out now. MSXML 6.0 wasn't available when Delphi 7 (and 2007) was released.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) which has an interface compatible with MSXML. There is also [SimpleStorage](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/&ei=4G0JTuz0FIfysgaPy4m4Dg&usg=AFQjCNF4Iquf3smfd1jt2dlWnH3ape6iWw) a set of interfaces on top of OmniXML that make it even stronger and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

[himXML](http://www.delphipraxis.net/130751-himxml-gesprochen-himix-ml.html) works also fine and fast.

- support unicode
- is under MPL v1.1 , GPL v3.0 or LGPL v3.0
- it fast
- its simple

you can get it from german [delphi-praxis](http://www.delphipraxis.net/130751-himxml-gesprochen-himix-ml.html) website.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DiXML](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/xml/index), which is build on the libxml2, libxslt and libexslt libraries (DIXml requires no DLLs or any other external files whatsoever).