# EDOMParseError ErrorCode list

Tags: delphi, xml-parsing, txmldocument

Where I can find the list of `EDOMParseError.ErrorCode` values?

I can't find it in Delphi source or in MSDN.

For example, if I set `XMLDocument.FileName` to incorrect url, I've got

```
Error code: -2146697210
Reason:  System error: -2146697210
```

Where this codes are defined?

Comment: "Where I can find ...?"  Where have you already looked?

Comment: Updated. I've search in Delphi sources and in msdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using MSXML as the DOM provider for `TXMLDocument`, the `EDOMParseError.ErrorCode` value is a COM [`HRESULT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx) value (MSXML is implemented as COM objects).  There is no single source that documents all possible `HRESULT` values.  Different modules are allowed to define their own custom `HRESULT` values.

In this case, -2146697210 (hex 0x800C0006) is `INET_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND` (The object was not found):

```
#define INET_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND          _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x800C0006L)
```

This translates to an `HRESULT` defined via the [`MAKE_HRESULT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694497.aspx) macro with a severity of `SEVERITY_ERROR`, a facility of `FACILITY_INTERNET`, and an error code of 6:

```
#define INET_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND          MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_INTERNET, 6)
```

This particular `HESULT` value is documented in [URL Moniker Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145.aspx). All `HRESULT` values with a facility of `FACILITY_INTERNET` belong to the WinInet library, which includes the UrlMon module.  MSXML uses WinInet internally to download remote content.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Reason, this error comes from your system.

```
SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode)
```

Should do what you want.

Call SysErrorMessage only if the error comes from the system. But now you need to figure out how to know this. Checking the Reason like this is possible

```
if reason.StartsWith('System Error') then
    errorMessage := SysErrorMessage(errorCode);
```

But it seems bad to do it this way (does it depends on the Windows language settings ?...)

Comment: I do not need the description for given code. I need the list of variants to case handle the parse fails.

Comment: I don't know where you would find such a list. -2146697210 is $800C0006 in hex, and you'll find that mentioned in @RobKennedy's comment on this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346060/error-when-loading-valid-windows-1252-document-system-error-2146697210